# Installing qiskit-aer through pip fails

Tags: python, cmake, pip, qiskit

I'm trying to install qiskit on Win10.
I typed in my admin cmd :
`pip install qiskit`

It goes just fine for terra, ignis, and aqua.
However, I have a C compiler problem when installing aer.
Here's the error message :

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.18363.959]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install qiskit
Processing c:\users\bohro\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\4d\00\27\1b79b2da1898a0d95508661eb1922c6d44be088f2719708a98\qiskit-0.19.6-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-ignis==0.3.3 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-aqua==0.7.3 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra==0.14.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.14.2)
Collecting qiskit-aer==0.5.2
  Using cached qiskit-aer-0.5.2.tar.gz (10.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy!=0.19.1,>=0.19 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ignis==0.3.3->qiskit) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.1.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ignis==0.3.3->qiskit) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.17 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ignis==0.3.3->qiskit) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ignis==0.3.3->qiskit) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio!=1.1.0,>=1.0.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (1.25.7)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-ntlm>=1.1.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets<8,>=7 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fastdtw in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy>=1.3 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: quandl in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: docplex in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (2.15.194)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (5.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dlx in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.3 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ply>=3.10 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (3.11)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow<4,>=3 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: retworkx>=0.3.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow-polyfield<6,>=5.7 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (5.9)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fastjsonschema>=2.10 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (2.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-constraint>=1.4 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.14.2->qiskit) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.27.1 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.5.2->qiskit) (0.29.21)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.4 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.5.2->qiskit) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.17->qiskit-ignis==0.3.3->qiskit) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.17->qiskit-ignis==0.3.3->qiskit) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ntlm-auth>=1.0.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.3 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.2->qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from sympy>=1.3->qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: inflection>=0.3.1 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from quandl->qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.14 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from quandl->qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (0.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from quandl->qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.14->quandl->qiskit-aqua==0.7.3->qiskit) (2017.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.7.2->qiskit) (2.20)
Building wheels for collected packages: qiskit-aer
  Building wheel for qiskit-aer (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bohro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bohro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\bohro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-a8l2_d9y'
       cwd: C:\Users\bohro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\qiskit-aer\
  Complete output (181 lines):


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Programs/cygwin64/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Programs/cygwin64/bin/cc - broken
  CMake Error at C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/.eggs/cmake-3.18.0-py3.6-win32.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
    The C compiler

      "C:/Programs/cygwin64/bin/cc"

    is not able to compile a simple test program.

    It fails with the following output:

      Change Dir: C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

      Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/bohro/Documents/Programs/ninja-win/ninja.exe cmTC_ba073 && ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: AccÃžs refusÃš.






    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.6 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qiskit-aer
  Running setup.py clean for qiskit-aer
Failed to build qiskit-aer
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for qiskit-aer which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: qiskit-aer, qiskit
    Running setup.py install for qiskit-aer ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bohro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bohro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bohro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-di0j_g0q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\Include\qiskit-aer'
         cwd: C:\Users\bohro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\qiskit-aer\
    Complete output (181 lines):


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Programs/cygwin64/bin/cc
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Programs/cygwin64/bin/cc - broken
    CMake Error at C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/.eggs/cmake-3.18.0-py3.6-win32.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
      The C compiler

        "C:/Programs/cygwin64/bin/cc"

      is not able to compile a simple test program.

      It fails with the following output:

        Change Dir: C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

        Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/bohro/Documents/Programs/ninja-win/ninja.exe cmTC_762f9 && ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: AccÃžs refusÃš.






      CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
      Generator

        Visual Studio 15 2017

      could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator - failure
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
      The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

        cl

      is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

      To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
      that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
      unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
      Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

      Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
      variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
      the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
      The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

        cl

      is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

      To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
      that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
      unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
      Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

      Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
      variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
      the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/bohro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l0zhdsp2/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ********************************************************************************
    scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

    Building windows wheels for Python 3.6 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
    Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

      https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

    ********************************************************************************
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bohro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bohro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l0zhdsp2\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bohro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-di0j_g0q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\Include\qiskit-aer' Check the logs for full command output.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

From what I understand, the problem is related to cygwin (which has already caused me much trouble - never using it again, gotta keep it for now because of university projects that require it). I've installed Cmake, i can open cmake-gui.
But I don't know how to get this compiler to be used by pip.

Moreover, contrary to what the error message says, I do have Visual Studio...

Thanks for the help,
Kal8578

Comment: What version of `pip` are you using? [Qiskit's installation guide](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html) says that pip 19 or higher is needed to install

Comment: I'm using pip 20.2.1. I upgraded it before posting here (I posted on SO when I definitely ran out of ideas to fix my problem)

Comment: You have the Visual Studios Build Tools installed as well? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/. The compiler should be installed from these build tools.

Comment: Yes, I do have them. And I have everything that' related to C that comes with it...

Comment: You can try running the installation without using the cache. You can do this by running the usual pip install with an extra flag: `pip install --no-cache-dir qiskit`

Comment: It didn't work either :/
I also tried to force the use of the cmake compiler by editing env variable, it still doesn't work with the same error message, with anything about the cygwin C compiler replaced by the corresponding thing about cmake. As I know for sure that my cmake works just fine, things hence got worse than I expected...
My temporary (or maye not) solution was to install anaconda, which I didn't use before, thus allowing me to have a second copy of Python, in 3.8 version (my everyday version, used when posting, is 3.6). After that, I pip installed qiskit through the conda term.

Comment: Even though the problem isn't really solved (it ain't super practical/handy to have two Pythons, cf. my previous post), thanks @MatthewStypulkoski for the time that you took so far to help me, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here was that you were using a 32 bit version of python. Qiskit Aer is only published as precompiled binaries on pypi for win64, so when you run `pip install qiskit` pip looks at the precompiled binaries available on pypi for qiskit-aer and doesn't see any that are compatible with python win32 it is running from. It then falls back to using the sdist (source package) and trying to install it from source. Unfortunately the aer build system is kind of a mess, especially on windows, and it rarely works without manual intervention. You don't actually need anaconda to easily install on windows just a 64bit version of python.

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for your answer.
It seems completely legit looking at what python versions I have. I wouldn't have guessed that ; I think that it should be made clear on the qiskit intall page [link](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html) that python 64 bits is required. The only thing that mentions 64-bits applies to the whole system, which is not the same thing. This being especially true when the error messages are as unclear as the ones I had.
Thanks again for the clarification, 
Kal8578

Comment: The latest release of qiskit-aer, 0.7.0, now builds and publishes win32 binaries as well. So this issue shouldn't happen in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here's a workaround that I found.

*Disclaimer : this solution ain't perfect as it requires you to install another Python / reinstall Python in its entirety.*

1/ Download Anaconda 3, and install it for Python 3.8, 64 bits.

2/ Through the Anaconda Powershell Prompt (and not your usual cmd), pip install qiskit.

3/ You should be able to run qiskit in a Anaconda Jupyter notebook (ensure that you use Anaconda's Jupyter, and not another Jupyter that was previously installed).

So that's my "solution". It obviously ain't perfect, as if (like me) you already had a non-Anaconda Python and used it for certain tasks, you end up having two Pythons, which is overall not a good thing as it may create conflicts.
If you do not care that much about fully uninstalling your Python and then follow the steps above, it's a good thing to do if you want to run qiskit on your own notebooks.

*(As this solution has the major flaw of requiring another Python install, I still am open to any idea that could help me solve my initial problem. Thanks, Kal8578)*